# How to I setup a VM with GUI

Tags: hyper-v

I've created a VM on Hyper-v(windows 10). When I start the server, it loads with a black screen. Withe the cursor blinking

Ive created the VM as suggested by their docs.

Comment: P.S. I am using Hyper V activated on windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was that I was missing an OS installation, the site suggested to click finish, which added the VM without the OS by default